# How to Filter JSON.parse results

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, shopify, zapier

I have been trying to filter the results of an API call based on my "note" value. I've been building it on Zapier and the call works but I cannot seem to find a way to make a filter function do its job (so if I replace line 19-23 with `return results`; then it gives me all orders from the api call). I've poured over every stack document I could find but they all end with the error `result.filter not found`, or a `bargle` error (generic error in Zapier).

```js
const options = {
  url: `https://mystorename.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {

  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
 
var results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
var queryItem = "555-5555"
const filteredOrders = results.orders.filter(item => item.note === queryItem);
   return filteredOrders;
  
});
```

And this is an example of my current output with `return results;` and no filter:

```js
{
  "orders": [
     {
      "note": "555-5555",
      "subtotal_price": "1.00"
     },
     {
      "note": "555-6666",
      "subtotal_price": "2.00"
     } 
  ]
}
```

Again the goal is to filter by the value in the "note" key. So if my filter input is 555-5555 then it should return all information for that item only. I did try to use an if statement for return, stringify instead of parse, covert to array...all with needed code, but regardless of the format I find filter does not work or nothing is returned. Going to keep working on it, so if I happen to find the answer I will post that, but at this point I feel stuck.

Comment: try `results.orders.filter`

Comment: No joy, it returns an undefined. Doubled checked my output and it is as I posted but  to get the each item I had to put in `return results.orders[0];` or `return results.orders[1];`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the method `filter` in a object but filter is only available in an array so you should try to call `filter` in the orders array.

```
let results = {
  "orders": [
     {
      "note": "555-5555",
      "subtotal_price": "1.00"
     },
     {
      "note": "555-6666",
      "subtotal_price": "2.00"
     } 
  ]
}

let queryItem = "555-5555";

let newArray = results.orders.filter(function (item) {
  return item.note == queryItem
})

console.log(newArray)
```

**Updated to contain a real http call:**

```
const url = 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d9466142f000058008ff6b7'

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
}

const response = await fetch(url, options)
const results = await response.json()

const queryItem = "555-5555"
const filteredOrders = results.orders.filter(item => item.note === queryItem)

console.log(filteredOrders)
```

Comment: That does work as is, but if I change to `let results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);` if fails. Is that something to do with JSON.parse causing the problem that needs to change?

Comment: @littlecoder I am not familiar with shopify or zappier and I don't know what that `z` is.
But I updated the response with a real http call and its working. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's the weird thing, both of your answers do 'work' but not in zapier for some reason. I have a ticket open with their support on this right now. I think the `z` is how they do object: "...is provided as the first argument to all function calls in your app." But the documentation doesn't mention z.filter that i've found.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to filter on `results`, but according to your output, you should be filtering on `results.orders`.

```
const filteredOrders = results.orders.filter(item => item.note === queryItem);
```

Comment: I did forget the `results.orders` part. I tried your answer but if still fails to filter. I added it to my original question (maybe I implemented it wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting all the orders back (all the orders with the specified filter value)?

I realized I wasn't getting back all orders and this did the trick:

```
`https://mystorename.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?status=any`
```

Alternatively, you can query the orders with that specific note:

```
`https://mystorename.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?status=any&note=` + queryItem
```

Comment: I actually started with this and realized that `note=queryItem` pulls all orders and not just the one with the unique note. Did you format the `queryItem` portion in a particular way not mentioned?

Comment: Ah, it looks like there might be an issue on shopify's end with the Orders API. This does not work as it should per the documentation. A few things that you might want to try (1) Make sure your endpoint contains `status=any&limit=250`  (2) your api has full access/scope to orders - `read_all_orders` `read_orders, write_orders`